# Binding to Window Events in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, window

I have read several posts on how to get the window settngs from the property and bind them "twoway" in the Window XAML when using the MVVM model. But, invariably, the author ends up saving them in the code behind as

```
void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); 
}
```

I would like to set the MainWindow XAML to bind to a class routine that saves the Properties. I would think there should be someting like:

```
WindowClosing="{Binding MyClosingEventRoutine}"
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the EventTrigger behavior from blend SDK or MVVM Light. on Window closing your command in your viewmodel is called.

```
<Window xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyClosingEventRoutine}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your post but I'm guessing you are doing MVVM, seeing as you don't like the old code behind? If so you can just grab some of the code from the MVVM frameworks out there that do events to commands.  This will then allow you to bind the windows closing event to a command in your viewmodel as per the following [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/HouseOfBilz/archive/2009/08/27/adventures-in-mvvm-ndash-binding-commands-to-any-event.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I changed the text to reflect MVVM. Thanks for your response but it is not very helpful in my situation where I'm looking for the binding keyword for the _Closing event.

Comment: No, it is in fact very helpful in your situation.  You can't bind to the closing event, just like you can't bind to the buttons click event.  You can however bind to the buttons "command".  There is no "command" for the window closing event so you need to use an event to command pattern like the MVVM frameworks have.  Why else do you think the MVVM frameworks have them?